# Uncaught type error when trying to install keycloak-js with vue and webpack: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_keycloak_js__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, keycloak

I am trying to install keycloak-js in my vue project as [described in this tutorial](https://medium.com/keycloak/secure-vue-js-app-with-keycloak-94814181e344) and when I start my application I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_keycloak_js__ is not a function
```

These are my entries in package.json

```
"keycloak-js": "^7.0.0",
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
```

Like in the tutorial I import it with `import * as Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'` and start it with `let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions)` which is the line that throws the error.

I also tried to require keycloak and then it just said `Keycloak is not a function`.

Could this error be webpack-related? This is imho the only difference between the tutorial and my application. I haven't found anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-worker just told me to try an older version of Keycloak and now it works.

```
"keycloak-js": "^6.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supposedly a bug in keycloak.js version 7.0.0 itself and as far as I know will be patched very soon. Until then I would stick to the latest 6.* version, which is 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the Keycloack with:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
```

Comment: I tried and it also says `Keycloak is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

The keycloak-js 7.x as installed via npm/yarn is broken.  The main `keycloak.js` file includes minified code for dependencies `js-sha256` and `base64-js` inline, and both clobber the `module.exports`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using a newer keycloak-js adapter. They changes the keycloak instance from type to class. Therefore the error. I managed to implement keycloak-js adapter 21.0.1 with Vue 3 Vite, without any third party libraries Given you entered your keycloak configurations correctly, you should be able to perform GET-Requests to your backend by passing your URI into the inputfield, logging in/out with kecloak and seeing some details of your end-user This is a ready to use solution for creating an instance of keycloak and passing it to the App.vue. A realm, a client and an user with given roles should already exist on your keycloak server, in order to perform a GET-request to your backend application, after keycloak login. Using spring security 6 cors and csrf should be configured properly too.

Take a look on my github.

https://github.com/JMaratkanov/Vue-vite_with_Keycloak_21.0.1_noThirdPartyLibs